# Security question - Anyone can update order status in WooCommerce with the correct url and own bearer token

Tags: wordpress, security, woocommerce

I figured out that you can `update` an order status and even add products with a WooCommerce endpoint:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order

The only thing that you need is your own bearer token when you are logged in. Then you can set the status to `paid` and the webshop owner thinks that you paid the order.

When the status of the order is set to `paid`, you can edit the order and add more products to it.

How can we secure this issue? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: If you believe this is a bug/security hole in WooCommerce then you should report it. Stack Overflow is not an official support channel for WooCommerce.

Comment: woo api is not public.

Comment: @MartinMirchev What do you mean by that? I can access it via postman. So if I can do it, why a regular customer can't?

Comment: When customer try to access without authentication will return {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}

Comment: Yeah but a customer can grab his own Bearer token and use that as authentication right? The customers knows his credentials. Grab their own token, and use the order endpoint. Or am I missing something?